# UWP - can't access values in ItemsPanel

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, itemspanel

I have the following XAML but I can't seem to access the contents of the ItemsWrapGrid in the corresponding .CS file - can anyone tell me what I should be doing (here's the code behind and xaml) :

```
private void wifiTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("in here " + e.GetType().ToString());
            ItemsWrapGrid wg = (ItemsWrapGrid) sender;

            Debug.WriteLine(e.OriginalSource.ToString());
            foreach (Control c in wg.Children)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Control " + c.Name);

            }

            Debug.WriteLine("leaving ");
        }





<GridView VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding nets}" x:Name="GDView" ItemClick="gdViewClick" >
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Name="configDataTemplate" x:DataType="data:wifiNets" >
                    <StackPanel Height="300" Width="350" Margin="10" Name="dtStackPanel" >
                        <Image Source="Assets\wifiIcon.png" Width="200" Height="201"  />
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="Name" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                            <TextBlock Name="configSSID" Width="auto"  Text="{x:Bind NetSSID}" FontSize="24" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="Strength"  Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                            <!--<TextBlock Name="configStrength" Width="auto" Text="{x:Bind NetSSIDStrength}" FontSize="20" />-->
                            <ProgressBar Name="configProgBar" Maximum="5" Value="{x:Bind NetSSIDStrength}" Foreground="Green"  />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="Connected" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                            <TextBlock Name="configConnectedTo" Text="{x:Bind NetSSIDConnected}" FontSize="20"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>

            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ItemsWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="10" Orientation="Vertical"  Tapped="wifiTapped" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        </GridView>
```

Just to be clear, when I run this I have three items of data (so it's working) - but what I'd like to be able to do is click on any one of the three data items and be able to identify the individual controls and their values within the data panel.

Thanks in advance, this is driving me nuts.
Paul.

Comment: As I can see so far, wifiTapped() is defined for ItemsWrapGrid at whole. Why you don't employ gdViewClick() instead? And all after all, UWP intends MVVM approach so could you try to move your logic to viewmodel instead of code-behind?

Comment: I have to check properly, but I believe that `Children` and `ItemsSource` are two completely different things. Did you try to access `ItemsSource` in your code-behind?

Comment: hi guys, I used Jonny's comments below and did a cast of the e.clickeditem to the type of the bound data - this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `IsItemClickEnabled` to true on your GridView, and hook into the ItemClick event on the GridView itself. From the event args, you can get the sender (most likely the `GridViewItem` UI element itself, of which your `DataTemplate` content is a child), and the `ClickedItem`, which is the bound datacontext of the datatemplate - in your case the instance of the `data:wifiNets` - which if your bindings work mean you won't actually have to look in the VisualTree at all.

If for some reason you want to recurse through the VisualChildren for the items of any ItemsControl, use the `ContainerFromIndex` or `ContainerFromItem` methods on the ItemsControl to get the ItemContainer hosting each instance of the datatemplate - although I wouldn't recommend doing this unless you really need too. Ideally you shouldn't often have a need for manually trawling the visual tree.